# how change in hashcode implementation effect on hashSet

Tags: java, data-structures, collections, hashmap

I had implemented hashSet and i had added some objects but later we had changed the hashcode implementation.

1>what will happen in this case,

2>what to do to prevent the change in hashcode implementaion

Comment: What do you mean "changed in run time"?

Comment: If you changed the hashcode implementation, then you compiled and redeployed new code, so you had to rebuild the hashset when your restarted your code, so what is the problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As very often, the answers are: it depends.

Assume that you change the hashCode() implementation of one of your classes.

1) if ( your application does not persist its data )
  then, when you restart your application, every piece will be using the new implementation. thus: no problem

2) if ( your application does persist its data )
  then, when you restart your application will reload its data; and depending on how/where you changed hashCode() ... interesting things might occur.

For your second question; there is no generic way to "solve" that, but there are well known practices, and if you follow them, chances get smaller that somebody messes up:

1) Education and skill: try to make sure that everybody touching code knows what he is doing (and not blindly following orders "but you told me to do xyz, so I sat down and did exactly xyz, not considering at all what the consequences are")

2) Good design, and re-use of existing components. Like: standard java comes with "known" good sets, maps, collections. Why do you think that you have to re-invent the wheel, and why do you think that your implementation will be "better"?

3) Good tests. Do TDD, and make sure that each new function has unit tests that cover all its behavior. And then make sure that your unit tests run automatically when somebody pushes code into your version control system; so you notice when stuff gets broken. Beyond that, build reasonable function/integration tests for those aspects that can't be tested by unit tests.